# Excel Function: if two cells in a row both start with the same two characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling to figure out how to create such a function. I'm looking for a formula that will identify if two cells in a specified range contain duplicate first two characters. Example below:

| Row 1 | AB - 12340 | BC -34239 | CD - 54656 | AB - 56432 | BC - 85678 |

I would like a formula that will output "bad" when it sees that the first two characters of "AB" and "BC" exists twice in that row.

Any help is appreciated! I've been struggling with this one for hours.

This is what I've tried so far: =IF(LEFT(A1:E1,"AB"),"good","bad")
Evidently, the problem is I can only search for one duplicate set of first characters. This would become extremely tedious. Plus, this returns a spill error.

Comment: FWIW, Conditional Formatting (CF) can highlight more than one set of duplicates, BUT, you will have to split out the first 2 characters into helper columns, and CF these. Also, CF will do All the cells in the range, so if you only want duplicates within a row you will need a New CF per Row. Obviously, this is pretty easy in VBA, but do you want to go that way? (How many rows, and how often do you want to do this?)

Comment: `=IF(LEFT(A1:E1,2)="AB","good","bad")`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try-

```
=LET(x,LEFT(A1:E1,2),y,UNIQUE(x),BYCOL(y,LAMBDA(col,IF(SUM(--(x=col))>1,"BAD","GOOD"))))
```

[image]